# Where to find RingCentral business-address email address?

Tags: settings, email-address, ringcentral

The following `business-address` endpoint

- URL: `/restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/business-address`
- Ref: https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefGetAccountBusinessAddress

returns an email address property but it's coming back empty for me. There's no email address field on the Company Info page in the Online Account Portal UI at https://service.ringcentral.com:

`Admin Portal` > `Phone System` > `Company Info` > `Company Address`

The API Reference shows the following example response:

```
{
  "uri" : "https.../restapi/v1.0/account/1215058004/business-address",
  "businessAddress" : {
    "street" : "13 Elm Street",
    "city" : "Foster City",
    "state" : "CA",
    "zip" : "94404",
    "country" : "United States"
  },
  "company" : "MyCompany Inc.",
  "email" : "firstname.lastname@mycompany.com"
}
```

Can you tell me what config/UI element maps to the email address returned by the business-address endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `account/business-address` API endpoint `email` property corresponds to the following UI field in the Online Account Portal - https://service.ringcentral.com :

`Admin Portal` > `Phone System` > `Company Info` > `Directory Assistance` > `Email`

The fields on that page will change the `businessAddress`, `company`, and `email` fields in the `account/business-address` API endpoint.

> **Note:** `Directory Assistance` is not available in the Sandbox Account and can only be viewed/updated in Production.

Here is a screenshot from this knowledge base article:

https://success.ringcentral.com/knowledge/TOCArticleRendererPkb.apexp?id=kA280000000GscW

[image]